# visual studio after rebuild, modified my code become not workable

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Hi i am using xamarin to develop my code, however, after i update the nuget package which is they asked me to do, after i rebuild the project, everything ruined up. This is not the first case i meeting this kind of weird thing from microsoft so i am seeking help from you all. This is my designer class for the xamarin.

[image]

After i rebuild, the code become this,

[image]

The magic happened, the rebuild works ! it wrote success, but full of red line in my code

[image]

am i am able to use back my old code after i rebuild it?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project before build?

Comment: yes, i tried a lot of way, cleaning is one of it, however it seem like downgrade the xamarin nuget package is the only way works for me, i think the latest xamarin form nuget package is not stable

Comment: Xamarin hasn't seen a stable moment in its history, that's why many are waiting for Microsoft to fix it. Currently it's not "weird thing from Microsoft" whatever Xamarin is messing up.